# Anyone want to try a script bash or python?

Tags: mysql, replication, logs, python

I need to automate master binary log purging to occur so that purging never goes back further than the last slave has the updated info for.

These slaves are mobile and there are 3 of them, and sync whenever the users get around to it.

I can do this manually but how to set this up in a script eludes me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

DISCLAIMER : Not a Python Programmer

I can give you a generic algorithm

Let's say you have 4 DB Servers

- `replicator@10.1.2.%` is the Replication User
- 1 Master (10.1.2.10)
- 3 Slaves (IP Addresses : 10.1.2.20,10.1.2.30,10.1.2.40)

STEP 01) Run this query

```
SELECT host FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE user = 'replicator';
```

Collect `host` columns into a list.

STEP 02) For each `host` collected into the list, run

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
```

and retrieve the `Relay_Master_Log_File` column. Collect these in an array.

I wrote about why to pick that field and not `Read_Master_Log_File`

- `Aug 02, 2012` : [Deleting bin logs in replication environment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21922/deleting-bin-logs-in-replication-environment/21924#21924)
- `May 26, 2012` : [Trying to understand SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18433/trying-to-understand-show-slave-status-g/18438#18438)
- `Jan 24, 2012` : [Mysql master-master replication auto flush old logs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11487/mysql-master-master-replication-auto-flush-old-logs/11488#11488)
- `Jan 03, 2012` : [what are the conditions under which mysql replication might break?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10029/what-are-the-conditions-under-which-mysql-replication-might-break/10089#10089)

STEP 03) Sort the array of `Relay_Master_Log_File` names. Select the first entry.

Suppose you collected

- `mysql-bin.00124`
- `mysql-bin.00123`
- `mysql-bin.00125`

After sorting, you would pick `mysql-bin.00123`

STEP 04) Purge binary logs on the Master using the select binary log

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.00123';
```

That's it.

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rolando's general description I would recommend your script maintains and expected configuration definition to compare against the active process list.  Rolando's steps only very *connected slaves*.  A likely scenario a slave would fall so far behind many bin logs is replication broken or was administratively stopped and not in the masters process list at all.

Treat an event of a missing slave as an error state in which no binary logs are purged from the master.

This does add the additional admin overhead of needing to keep that config list in sync when adding/removing slaves but required for your script to work as desired.

Further consider your retention policy. If you want to spin up a new slave you might do that by restoring a recent backup and restarting replication from when the backup was taken.  For the scope of this discussion we'll assume you have daily backups and are certain the binlog position stored with the backups have been proven to be working correctly.

If you have daily backups you'd probably want to keep at least 2 days of bin logs.

Edit: After rereading your post it sounds like your question is more a long the lines of "how to write scripts".  Python is certainly a viable option suited for the task.  Whether it's perl, python, php or other you'll need to look up how to work with their MySQL API clients.  More specific questions of how-to-code in these languages are probably better placed in stackoverflow.com after googling some basic intro's to the language to gain that literacy.

Answer (score 0):

draw backs of this script.
1.you don't have chance to recover db when ever crash.if you maintain incremental backups in a backup server than it is ok).

you can better to enable expire_logs.
or
you purge the bin-logs using date time in the script.